# Cast Exception When Using Foreach on Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCollection

Tags: service, casting, csom

I have exhausted my resources on this issue. I'm hoping you all can assist me.

I have an agent polling Microsoft O365 for list collections in order to walk through all the lists in a given site. Here is the code:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client = CSOM
ListCollection lists = CSOM.web.Lists;
clientContext.Load(lists);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
try
{
   foreach(CSOM.List list in lists
   {
      do.stuff()
   }
}
catch(Excetion ex)
{
   // I get this excetpion in my log at CSOM.List after 'in lists' is read.
   /*System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 
    'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' 
     to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List'.*/
}
```

When in debug and tracing through the code ex appears 'null', but I still get the excetion in my debug logs when I write `ex.ToString()` to a log file.
I am using .Net 4.6. This code has worked before, during dev tests, but wont work running in a service. I can't find any Namespace issues. The O365 account I amusing has 2FA disabled and has admin rights. Any thoughts would be very helpful. Thank you.